# Keycloak registration says login details are incorrect

Tags: keycloak

I have a frontend application connected to Keycloak for user authentication. Currently, users can log in successfully, but I'd like to enable user self-registration for account creation so I enabled it but now when I click on "Register" in the browser to create a new account, Keycloak returns an error message saying, "Invalid username or password." I've tried searching online for a solution, but I couldn't find any relevant information. It appears to be related to a setting that might be blocking registrations.

I've watched several tutorials and it seems all I need to do is enable user registration in Keycloak but I am not able to find the correct setting.

Thank you in advance.